# How to Create a port scanner TCP SYN using the method (TCP SYN )?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#####################################
# Portscan TCP         #
# #
#####################################
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket

ip = input("Digite o IP ou endereco: ")

ports = []
count = 0

while count < 10:
    ports.append(int(input("Digite a porta: ")))
    count += 1


for port in ports:
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.settimeout(0.05)
    code = client.connect_ex((ip, port)) #conecta e traz a msg de erro
#Like connect(address), but return an error indicator instead of raising an exception for errors
    if code == 0: #0 = Success
        print (str(port) + " -> Porta aberta")
    else:
        print (str(port) + " -> Porta fechada")

print ("Scan Finalizado")
```

The python script above is a TCP Scanning. How can I change it into a TCP SYN scanning ? How to Create a port scanner TCP SYN using the method (TCP SYN ) ?

Comment: Um, that's a bit different than  just trying to connect. You will have to come with an approach of your own and ask a *precise* question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Upsampled mentioned, you might use raw sockets (https://en.wikipedia.org/) as you only need a subset of TCP protocol (send **SYN** and recieve **RST-ACK** or **SYN-ACK**
).

As coding something like http://www.binarytides.com/raw-socket-programming-in-python-linux/
could be a good excersice, I would also suggest to consider https://github.com/secdev/scapy

> Scapy is a powerful Python-based interactive packet manipulation
>   program and library.

Here's the code sample that already implements a simple port scanner
http://pastebin.com/YCR3vp9B and a detailed article on what it does:
http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/build-stealth-port-scanner-with-scapy-and-python-0164779/

The code is a little bit ugly but it works — I've checked it from my local Ubuntu PC against my VPS. 
Here's the most important code snippet (slightly adjusted to conform to PEP8):

```
# Generate Port Number
srcport = RandShort()

# Send SYNC and receive RST-ACK or SYN-ACK
SYNACKpkt = sr1(IP(dst=target) /
                TCP(sport=srcport, dport=port, flags="S"))

# Extract flags of received packet
pktflags = SYNACKpkt.getlayer(TCP).flags

if pktflags == SYNACK:
    # port is open
    pass
else:
    # port is not open
    # ...
    pass
```

Answer (score 5):

First, you will have to generate your own SYN packets using RAW sockets. You can find an example [here](http://www.binarytides.com/raw-socket-programming-in-python-linux/)

Second, you will need to listen for SYN-ACKs from the scanned host in order to determine which ports actually try to start the TCP Handshake (SYN,SYN-ACK,ACK). You should be able to detect and parse the TCP header from the applications that respond. From that header you can determine the origin port and thus figure out a listening application was there.

Also if you implement this, you also basically made a SYN DDOS utility because you will be creating a ton of half-opened tcp connections.